# Start action after second click at element class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, addclass

i have small problem with my jquery function and i need help. So, i have button with close function but this close function must be fire up after some special class added. So at first click at this close button i'm adding class `.major_list`. Now i need to close some panel after this specify class click... It's working but panel closing after first click when i use .live function, co you help my how to do this after second click and click at class `.major_list`?

this is my code:

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_01').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('major_list');
});

$('.major_list').delay(300).live('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    },600).stop(true,true);
});
```

much thx for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_01').click(function(){        
    if ($(this).hasClass("major_list")) {
        /* close */
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('major_list');
    }
});
```

Comment: You could add `$(this)` to a variable before the `if` statement :D

Comment: @jonathandey: I did have it that way originally, but `$(this)` will only be executed once no matter what, so I didn't see the need.